# Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure CLR_TRIGGER_NAUDOJASI, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'insert'

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I generated a `.sql` file from my physical data model which is created with Sybase PowerDesigner. And then I'm trying to execute that `.sql` in Microsoft SQL Server, I get an error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure CLR_TRIGGER_NAUDOJASI, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'insert'.

In these lines of code (insert, as and Assembly is underlined)

```
create trigger CLR_TRIGGER_NAUDOJASI 
on NAUDOJASI  insert as
   external name %Assembly.GeneratedName%.
go
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply forgot the `FOR` (or `AFTER`) keyword before the `INSERT`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER CLR_TRIGGER_NAUDOJASI 
ON dbo.NAUDOJASI  
FOR INSERT 
AS 
   external name %Assembly.GeneratedName%.
go
```

Before asking such a question, you should really consult the [SQL Server Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) on MSDN first! The have the **precise syntax** for any of the T-SQL commands for you verify!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have specified `Microsoft SQL Server` as the `Target DMBS` in the PowerDesigner. The syntax doesn't look like that for Microsoft T-SQL, it's probably the Sybase version (which is the default setting in PD).